# Reversing a string using a Stack ADT in Elm

Tags: stack, reverse, elm

```
import Html exposing (..)
import String

type alias Stack = List String


push : String -> Stack -> Stack
push tok stack = 
 (tok :: stack)


pop : Stack -> (Maybe String, Maybe Stack)
pop stack = 
 let 
   top = List.head stack 
 in 
 (top, List.tail stack)


reverseString: String -> String
reverseString incoming = 
 let 
   stringStack = incoming 
    |> String.split "" 
    |> List.foldl push [] 
 in 
   -- How to use pop() here?
   List.foldr String.append "" stringStack


main : Html 
main = 
 "Hello World!"
 |> reverseString
 |> toString 
 |> text
```

I am attempting on my own `reverse` of a string using `push()` and `pop()`. I am able to incorporate `push`, but not able to use `pop` within the function `reverseString`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to `List.foldr` with your Stack ADT, but that's cheating; if Stack is really an ADT, we shouldn't be able to exploit that its a list!

`List.foldr` also matches the Stack ADT poorly, because it frees its function argument from handling the empty list, whereas the `pop` function forces us to treat both the case of the non-empty and empty stack.

If we want a Stack ADT, we'll have to do recursion through the stack manually, without using `List.foldr`. First, it'll be convenient to reduce the `pop` function to more concisely represent the two cases of "empty stack" and "non-empty stack":

```
pop : Stack -> Maybe (String, Stack)
pop stack = 
  case stack of 
    [] -> Nothing
    x :: xs -> Just (x, xs)
```

Then we can formulate reverseString

```
reverseString : String -> String
reverseString string = 
  let
    loop stack = 
      case pop stack of 
        Nothing -> ""
        Just (symbol, stack') -> symbol ++ loop stack'
  in
    String.split "" string   -- Split the string into a list
    |> List.foldl push []    -- Push each letter on the stack
    |> loop                  -- Pop each letter off the stack
```

It is perhaps easier to work directly with lists. Then Cons `(::)` is push and `List.foldl` is the function that reduces a stack by popping until empty.

```
reverseString2 : String -> String
reverseString2 = 
  String.split ""        -- "String -> Stack" (implicitly pushes)
  >> List.foldl (::) []  -- "Stack -> List" (reduces the stack)
  >> String.join ""      -- "List -> String" (nothing to do with stacks)
```

Comment: Thanks for an amazing and thorough answer! Any particular reason for use of the variable `stack'` with an apostrophe?

Comment: It's just to indicate it's not the same as the original `stack` argument. You don't need to, but I think it makes the code a little clearer.

Comment: (If you like the answer, consider upvoting or accepting it. It makes it clear to others that they might find the answer useful, and it gives me the oh-so-satisfying little green box with a +10.)

Comment: To avoid "cheating", how can `reverseString` be modified not to use `List.foldl`?

Comment: It can't, really: Conceptually, you need to push each letter in the input string onto the stack. For that, you need to iterate over the input string. I don't know that there's a way to do that in Elm without converting that String to a List, and using `List.foldl` to iterate over that list. I don't think its cheating, though: `List.foldl` conceptually iterates over the input string, calling `push` for each letter. This is what we want!

Comment: How about use `peek()` to get the top value, and then `pop()` can be simplified to just return a stack?

Comment: Is the implementation of `pop` for stack ADT also equally "complex" in other functional languages (say Haskell or F#)?

Comment: ...and finally, will the cons/[uncons](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/String#uncons) from `String` package help make things simpler?

Comment: Peek: sure; but you won't get out of having to distinguish between empty/non-empty stack (now in Peek). Same thing for other languages: you have decide what pop does on the empty stack. F# and Haskell have exceptions, so that's an option for the empty stack. I believe the Elm approach where you *have* to handle both cases explicitly leads to more robust programs. I'm not familiar with cons/incomes in String, but sure, they might make it possible to get a clearer implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Elm doesn't have iteration at the language level so you need to use a data structure that supports iteration and mapping.  In this case, I think lazy list is likely the best as you won't blow the stack via recursion.

In this case, stackIterator yields a lazy list of string from a stack.  In order to get the lazy sequence of values we want, we need a function that we can repeatedly apply to its own result, and since pop returns a tuple of head, stack, that function is ((mhd, tl) -> pop tl).  The next parts operate as a pipeline, first pulling out the left part of the tuple, second promising to terminate the list if the returned stack top is Nothing, third, turning the list of `Maybe`s into strings via `Maybe.withDefault`.

By just substituting LL.foldr and the lazy list, you have a proper non-recursive iteration on your stack involving your pop function.

A couple of style notes:

- Your stack really wants String to be a type variable.
- As a style choice, you should prefer pattern match to functions returning maybe on lists.
- It makes the code cleaner if pop returns stack instead of maybe stack, since it can signal an empty stack via the maybe top result.
- My own elm style isn't perfect.  There's probably a clever way to compose `snd` and `pop` that doesn't require an explicit lambda binding.

  ```
  import Html exposing (..)
  import String
  import Lazy.List as LL exposing (LazyList)

  type alias Stack = List String


  push : String -> Stack -> Stack
  push tok stack = 
   (tok :: stack)


  pop : Stack -> (Maybe String, Stack)
  pop stack = 
   case stack of
     hd :: tl -> (Just hd, tl)
     _ -> (Nothing, [])

  stackIterator : Stack -> LazyList String
  stackIterator stack =
   LL.iterate (\(mhd, tl) -> pop tl) (pop stack)
    |> LL.map fst
    |> LL.takeWhile (\a -> a /= Nothing)
    |> LL.map (Maybe.withDefault "") -- Default just for theoretical completeness

  reverseString: String -> String
  reverseString incoming = 
   let 
    stringStack = incoming 
     |> String.split "" 
     |> List.foldl push [] 
   in 
     LL.foldr String.append "" (stackIterator stringStack)


  main : Html 
  main = 
   "Hello World!"
   |> reverseString
   |> toString 
   |> text
  ```

Comment: This will get rid of the lambda binding `LL.takeWhile ( flip (/=) Nothing)` but you may feel it does not buy you any extra clarity!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I modified [Rundberget's version](https://gist.github.com/rundis/8b5a0fd09c3eb348dfc2aa7e862436b4) to use String as a Stack. While it is not as generic as the other solutions, it does not use `List.foldr` or `List.foldl`, and ends up being somewhat shorter.

```
module SStack where

import String

type alias SStack = String

empty : SStack
empty =
  ""


push : String -> SStack -> SStack
push tok stacks = 
  tok ++ stacks


pop : SStack -> Maybe (Char, SStack)
pop stacks = 
  String.uncons stacks


reverse : SStack -> SStack
reverse stack =
  case (pop stack) of 
    Nothing ->
      empty
    Just(x, r) -> 
      push  (reverse r) (String.fromChar x)
```

and here's the driver module:

```
import SStack as Stack exposing (..)
import Html exposing (..)

reverseString : String -> String
reverseString str =
  Stack.reverse str 


main : Html.Html
main =
  reverseString "Hello World !" 
    |> Html.text
```